# "Stand-alone" TypeScript declaration merging for a module from Definitely Typed

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, .d.ts

I cannot get TypeScript [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to work on a particular module.

I provide below a *contrived* minimal example which shows where I am stuck. I have a single file `test.ts`:

```js
import { assert } from 'chai';

function f(x: string | undefined): string {

    assert.isDefined(x);    // equivalent to `assert(x !== undefined)`
    return x.toLowerCase();

}
```

Compiling as follows:

```bash
npm install typescript @types/chai chai --save
npx tsc --strict --lib "ES6,DOM" test.ts
```

I get the error message `error TS18048: 'x' is possibly 'undefined'`. This is because in the TypeScript [type definitions for `chai`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/0b620fc23929779b01c399e70e14827e56c8941f/types/chai/index.d.ts#L680) we have:

```js
isDefined<T>(value: T, message?: string): void;
```

I would like to "patch" this declaration with a TypeScript type assertion. The following works perfectly:

```js
import { assert } from 'chai';

// similar to TypeScript NonNullable utility type
type NonUndefined<T> = T extends undefined ? never : T;

declare global {
    namespace Chai {
        interface Assert {
            isDefined<T>(value: T, message?: string): asserts value is NonUndefined<T>;
        }
    }
}

function f(x: string | undefined): string {

    assert.isDefined(x);
    return x.toLowerCase();

}
```

But, I want this declaration to be in a separate file, e.g. `fix.d.ts` which is automatically picked up by TypeScript so that the original code snippet works without modification.

I've tried various incantations based on TypeScript [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) documentation, but can't quite get it. Is this possible?

At time of writing, I npm installed TypeScript version 5.1.6, `@types/chai` version 4.3.5, and `chai` version 4.3.7.

Answer (score 0):

If you were in a hurry you could write this

```
function f(x: string | undefined): string {
    assert.isDefined(x);
    return x!.toLowerCase();
}
```

The exclamation mark tells Typescript "Treat it as known to be not undefined".

Otherwise, not sure it is a good to try to extend the Chai namespace from inside your application.  I would encapsulate it -

```
interface MyAssert {
  isDefined<T>(x:T): asserts x is NonUndefined<T>;
};
const myassert: MyAssert = {
  isDefined<T>(x:T): asserts x is NonUndefined<T> {
    assert.isDefined(x);
  }
}
function f(x: string | undefined): string {
    myassert.isDefined(x);
    return x.toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Craig. I didn't know about the `!` functionality. Unfortunately, for this question, I really want to understand if what I want is possible, and if not, why not. In the general case, I would agree with your second point. But here, I would argue that I am actually correcting the type signature since `assert.isDefined(x)` is equivalent to `assert(x !== undefined)`, so we are guaranteed that if the function returns, then the input value is definitely defined.